# How make a TRUE paginated load more list on SwiftUI that load more data Up & Down?

Tags: swift, swiftui, pagination, scrollview

The common way to add a "load more" functionality assumes you start displaying from the start and add rows to the bottom.

But I wish to implement a true paginated list, like in Google, that can return a lot of "pages", and more important: Can allow links to a specific page.

ie:

```
First | 1 | 2 | 3 | Next | Last
```

But it will much nicer if I can give the illusion of smooth scrolling up/down as if all the results are on the screen, ie:

```
-- App Link to Page 3

Page: 3
Rows: 
 - F 
 - G
 - H
```

Then the user scrolls down and adding more rows to the bottom is easy.

But then the user scrolls *up*, and expect to see the results of Page 2:

```
-- App Link to Page 3

Page: 2 <-- How show this
Rows: 
 - C 
 - D
 - E


Page: 3
Rows: 
 - F 
 - G
 - H
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `ScrollView`, you can use `ScrollViewReader` in conjunction with its `scrollTo` method.

When the view loads, you can immediately scroll them to the middle of the list (e.g. "Page 3"). Since they aren't at the beginning, scrolling up will reveal content on previous pages.

You can read this `ScrollViewReader` tutorial: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-scroll-view-move-to-a-location-using-scrollviewreader.

---

You can also use `ScrollViewReader` to see where they are in the list—if they're at the top, then load previous pages?

Comment: Is this not required to have all the data(rows) already loaded? When you link to a google result search(page x) the data for the next/previous pages are not on the results, it will be loaded later. Making the illusion that data IS loaded (just not visible) is what I looking for...

Comment: In SwiftUI, lists are lazy loaded, so rows won't be loaded until the user scrolls near. Is that the behavior you want?